# How to make caption above in algorithm

Tags: captions, algorithms

How can I make the caption "Algorithm 1" be placed **above** the first line and the text still inside the two first lines?
And how can the line styles be changed in the algorithm environment?

```
\begin{algorithm}
\caption{Calculate $y = x^n$}
\label{alg1}
\begin{algorithmic}
\REQUIRE $n \geq 0 \vee x \neq 0$
\ENSURE $y = x^n$
\STATE $y \leftarrow 1$
\IF{$n < 0$}
\STATE $X \leftarrow 1 / x$
\STATE $N \leftarrow -n$
\ELSE
\STATE $X \leftarrow x$
\STATE $N \leftarrow n$
\ENDIF
\WHILE{$N \neq 0$}
\IF{$N$ is even}
\STATE $X \leftarrow X \times X$
\STATE $N \leftarrow N / 2$
\ELSE[$N$ is odd]
\STATE $y \leftarrow y \times X$
\STATE $N \leftarrow N - 1$
\ENDIF
\ENDWHILE
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You have to define a new float style:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{algorithm,algorithmic}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\floatc@ruled@gabriel[2]{#2\par}
\newcommand\fs@ruledgabriel{%
  \def\@fs@cfont{\bfseries}\let\@fs@capt\floatc@ruled@gabriel
  \def\@fs@pre{%
    {\@fs@cfont\strut\fname@algorithm\ \thealgorithm}\par
    \hrule height.8pt depth0pt \kern2pt
  }%
  \def\@fs@post{\kern2pt\hrule\relax}%
  \def\@fs@mid{\kern2pt\hrule\kern2pt}%
  \let\@fs@iftopcapt\iftrue}
\makeatletter
\floatstyle{ruledgabriel}
\restylefloat{algorithm}


\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}
\caption{Calculate $y = x^n$}
\label{alg1}
\begin{algorithmic}
\REQUIRE $n \geq 0 \vee x \neq 0$
\ENSURE $y = x^n$
\STATE $y \leftarrow 1$
\IF{$n < 0$}
\STATE $X \leftarrow 1 / x$
\STATE $N \leftarrow -n$
\ELSE
\STATE $X \leftarrow x$
\STATE $N \leftarrow n$
\ENDIF
\WHILE{$N \neq 0$}
\IF{$N$ is even}
\STATE $X \leftarrow X \times X$
\STATE $N \leftarrow N / 2$
\ELSE[$N$ is odd]
\STATE $y \leftarrow y \times X$
\STATE $N \leftarrow N - 1$
\ENDIF
\ENDWHILE
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

[image]